# Laravel 4 Eager Loading Multiple Table and Easy Access To The View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Hi guys I'm new to Laravel 4 PHP Framework and I know just a little. Just want to ask how to eager load 3 tables (or more) and give a view a clean way access to the variable (I have a table users, profile and statuses)

```
**Users Table**
id (int) ai
code (varchar)
email_id (int) ref to email table
username (varchar)
password (varchar)
softdeletes, timestamps, remember token laravel defaults

**Profile Table**
id (int) ai
user_id (int) index ref to users table
lastname (varchar)
firstname (varchar)
middlename (varchar)
birthdate (date)
and more...
laravel defaults...

**Statuses Table**
id (int) ai
user_id (int) index ref to users table
message (text)
laravel defaults...
```

The User model provided by laravel I just add a public function profile and statuses

```
<?php

class User extends \Eloquent {
    ......

public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}

public function statuses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Status');
}
}
```

The Profile and Statuses model

```
class Profile extends \Eloquent {

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
}

class Status extends \Eloquent {

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
}
```

In my HomeController index method I have declared a variable $user like this.

```
$user = User::with('profile', 'statuses')->whereId( Auth::id() )->first();

$statuses = $user->statuses;
```

Then I compact the statuses into my view and then run a

```
@foreach($statuses as $status)
    {{ $status->user->profile->firstname; }}

    {{ $status->message; }}
@endforeach
```

But I'm getting an error.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know, that Eloquent **relationships are not bidirectional.**

That being said, loading `statuses` on the `users` doesn't load `user` on each `status`:

```
$user = User::with('statuses')->first();
// query users table once and statuses table once

// now you can use statuses:
$user->statuses; // collection
$user->statuses->first(); // single status
```

BUT this is completely different story

```
$user->statuses->first()->user; 
// query users table for the user of this status
// despite you already loaded that user and stored in $user variable

// in your case you did that in your loop:
@foreach($statuses as $status)
  {{ $status->user->profile->firstname; }}
  // here you query users table AND profiles table again
```

So if you do that in a foreach loop, then you end up with as many queries, as there are statuses in the collection.

---

**Now, the easiest and most expressive way for you would be this:**

```
// controller
$user = Auth::user()->load('statuses', 'profile');
// the same as User::with('statuses', 'profile')->where('id', Auth::id())->first();

return View::make('some.view', compact('user'));
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach ($user->statuses as $status)

  // you can access the user, not affected by the loop
  $user->username

  // you can access the profile, not affected by the loop
  $user->profile->firstname

  // and of course each status in the loop
  $status->message

@endforeach
```

Comment: By using $user = Auth::user()->load('statuses', 'profile'); results in 3 queries 'select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1', 'select * from `profiles` where `profiles`.`user_id` in (?)', 'select * from `statuses` where `statuses`.`user_id` in (?)'

Comment: And now I can also check if the statuses table for a specific user is null buy using @unless($user->statuses-count()) in the view thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand in Blade view you should use:

```
{{ $user->profile->firstname }} {{ $user->profile->lastname }}  

@foreach ($user->statuses as $status)
  {{ $status->message }}  {{ $status->id}}
@endforeach
```

to get all status messages and ids for selected user.

**EDIT**

As you added more code, you should assign to your view both `$user` and `$statuses` variables.

Now you can do:

```
@foreach ($statuses as $status)

    {{ $user->profile->firstname }} {{ $user->profile->lastname }}

    {{ $status->message }}
@endforeach
```

because each user will be the same for those messages (you got from Database user with selected id)

But you can only assign `$user` to your view and the following code should work:

```
@foreach ($user->statuses as $status)

    {{ $user->profile->firstname }} {{ $user->profile->lastname }}

    {{ $status->message }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: No need for foreach? coz I want to grab a statuses with there fullname for my feeds section.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the user's firstname and lastname that have statuses
>   associated to there ids

Then you may try this (Notice `User::has('statuses')`, which will get users only who has `statuses`):

```
$user = User::has('statuses')
            ->with('profile', 'statuses')
            ->whereId(Auth::id())
            ->first();
```

Without `has('statuses')` you'll get all the users even they have not related statuses. Then in your `view`:

```
{{ $user->profile->firstname }}
{{ $user->profile->lastname }}
```